# Vectorize which function to get positions

Tags: r, vectorization, data.table

I have two data frames (`db1` and `db2`) and I want to get positions in `db2` that match some arguments in `db1`. This could be achieve using a `for` loop as follows:

```
db1 <- data.frame(id=rep(1:4,each=4),
                  class=sample(1:10, 16, replace=TRUE),
                  var=rnorm(16)
                  )
db2 <- expand.grid(id=1:4, class=1:10)
db2$x <- rnorm(nrow(db2))

for(i in 1:nrow(db1)) print(which(db2$id==db1$id[i] & db2$class==db1$class[i]))
```

However loops are very inefficient so I would like vectorizing this loop. It could be possible to pass a vector to the `which()` function so this functions search in db2 for each values in db1?

Comment: What do you want to do with said positions once you have them? In other words; is there a greater purpose than the initial request above? By the way, loops are not inefficient in R if you set the up correctly by allocating storage for the result object and fill that object whilst looping.

Comment: Once I get the positions my purpose will be to gather a range of data from the `db2` around the positions (+/- n positions) and add them to `db1` data set. I think my actual problem is that both `db1` (3x10^6 obs) and `db2` (1x10^6 obs) are huge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
db1 <- data.table(db1)
db2 <- data.table(db2)
# You can index by additional columns as necessary
setkeyv(db1, c("id","class"))
setkeyv(db2, c("id","class"))

# Show only records in db2 that match id and class with db1

db2[db1,]

      id class           x         var
 [1,]  1     1 -0.50266835  0.82391749
 [2,]  1     9 -1.21245991 -1.43163848
 [3,]  1     9 -1.21245991 -0.68622189
 [4,]  1    10 -0.28659235 -0.98107793
 [5,]  2     4  2.18779836  1.25841256
 [6,]  2     6  1.32407301  0.42287395
 [7,]  2     7 -0.53808409 -0.12069089
 [8,]  2    10 -0.67679146 -0.73930821
 [9,]  3     7  0.03133591  0.31142901
[10,]  3     8  0.78927215  1.86952233
[11,]  3     9 -0.04674115 -0.45102021
[12,]  3    10 -0.83388764 -0.04354332
[13,]  4     8  1.17608109 -0.07343352
[14,]  4     8  1.17608109 -0.00053299
[15,]  4     9  0.59344187 -0.21407897
[16,]  4    10 -2.06237055  0.78420146

# To just return an index of matching rows
db2[db1, which=T]

 [1]  1  9  9 10 14 16 17 20 27 28 29 30 38 38 39 40

# To get only unique row indices
> db2[unique(db1),which=T]
[1]  1  9 10 14 16 17 20 27 28 29 30 38 39 40
```

Answer (score 0):

If db1 and db2 have the same number of rows, print all db2 rows where db2 and db1 'id, class' are equal:

```
print(db2[db2$id == db1$id & db2$class == db1$class,])
```

The same query sorted by db2$id:

```
print(db2[order(db2[db2$id == db1$id & db2$class == db1$class,]$id, decreasing = TRUE))
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. What you propose is similar to a `merge`: `merge(db1, db2, by=c("id","class"))`. In addition, your proposal does not work since both `db1` and `db2` have different sizes.

Comment: The query only prints db2 rows, it does not merge the 2 data frames. But if they have different sizes it will not work.